# Telnet is not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, telnet

I'm new to Ubuntu and want to install Telnet and then enable it. I tried following commands-

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd
sudo apt-get install telnetd
```

Both were installed ,and I checked that which ports were open with-

```
netstat -tulpn
```

This showed me that 23 port was not opening and hence I can't open Telnet. I disabled Firewall disabled with-

```
sudo ufw diable
```

Do you have any idea? On another machine I installed the same way and it worked there, but now on my machine it is not working. Please help me to solve this problem. I also tried to restart Xinetd but it was not helpful.

Comment: I think you need to reboot for the firewall changes to take effect. You at least have to restart the `ufw` service. Try `sudo ufw 23` to just allow it and then `sudo service ufw restart` to restart the firewall.

Comment: @Zacharee1 thank you for answer, but it not help me

Comment: try restarting xinetd `sudo service xinetd restart`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Configure the /etc/inetd.conf file manually by adding the line
"telnet stream tcp nowait telnetd /usr/sbin/tcpd /usr/sbin/in.telnetd" to it with elevated permissions.

Then, configure the /etc/xinetd.conf file manually by adding

"instances = 60

log_type = SYSLOG authpriv

log_on_success = HOST PID

log_on_failure = HOST

cps = 25 30"

to the default settings section (with elevated permissions).

Restart Ubuntu.

Restart the telnet server by running the commnd "sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart".

When you finish, use the command "telnet -tln" to check to see if the telnet server successfully opened a socket for you on Port 23

If so, you should see a line in the output that looks like the following:

TCP 0 0 (your local address):23  0.0.0.0:* LISTENING

If so, run ifconfig to grab the IPv4 and take that over to your other machine (running the telnet client). In that terminal run "telnet (the IPv4 you wrote down)". If everything's configured correctly (it may take a few seconds depending on your connection speed) it should connect and prompt you for a username/password. Enter them and you're in.

Comment: For some extremely weird reason. The line was missing (telnet stream tcp nowait telnetd /usr/sbin/tcpd /usr/sbin/in.telnetd). Just adding it solved my problems. Thanks.